# React Native - Navigation

Tags: navigation-drawer, tabnavigator, stack-navigator

I am new to react native.

I am facing problem in react navigation. what I want to do is:

- From the **Parent** screen to a **NavDrawer** screen.
- **NavDrawer** has two screen, the 1st screen also has 2 other screen in  **TabBar**.
- **NavDrawer** has a **NavHeader** and we can also access the drawer by clicking on the menu button on left side of the **ActionBar**.

What problem I am facing is:

- Getting a **back arrow** sign on the **left side** of the **action bar** when I am navigating to **NavDrawer** from **Parent** screen using **Stack Navigator**.

Please can some one a demo code for those routing?

Comment: Half part of this here in working mode & please let me know still you are facing issue -    http://androidseekho.com/others/reactnative/switching-between-tabs-in-react-native/

Comment: @priyanka thank you for your response. I have removed the back arrow but there is new prob. The **ActionBar** (in android top bar is called actionbar) is also shown in **NavDrawer** when it is opened. You showed the **TabBar** , I have no issue with that.